# setProperty value from requested getParameter

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I want to give property `"host"` the value of the requested parameter `"ip"`, submitted using method Get in `form.html`

This is my `index.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Ip</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:directive.include file="form.html"/>
    <% if (request.getParameter("ip") == null || 
           request.getParameter("ip") == ""){%>
        Not connected!
    <% } else {%>
    <jsp:useBean id="connect" class="test.Ip" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="connect" property="host" value="Connect" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="connect" property="host" />
    <% }%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the included file `form.html`

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="GET">
    Connect to IP: <input type="text" name="ip"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Connect">
</form>
```

This is the Java file `Ip.java`

```
package test;

public class Ip{

    private String host;

    public String getHost(){
        return("Got value " +host);
    }
    public void setHost(String host){
        this.host = host;
    }
}
```

It returns the string "Got value Connect" instead of the value I type in the form.

Comment: `if (request.getParameter("ip") == null | ` change it to logical or `||` i.e. `if (request.getParameter("ip") == null ||`

Comment: Made the change but it does not solve my problem

Comment: `<jsp:setProperty name="connect" property="host" value="Connect" />` would set the property to `"Connect"`, not the `ip` GET parameter.

Comment: Yes it does, but how do I set the property to the `ip` GET parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to compare strings, you need to use method equals, as you will otherwise compare two object which will not be the same

Change:

```
request.getParameter("ip") == ""){%
```

To:

```
request.getParameter("ip").equals("")){%
```

then you want to set the property host to the parameter ip

Change:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="connect" property="host" value="Connect" />
```

To (As the name attribute of the textfield is ip and not Connect, that's the button):

```
<jsp:setProperty name="connect" property="host" param="ip" />
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to change the value tag to param (Value means setting the value to given string, param is to set a bean property to the value of any request parameter

Comment: If the names within the form and in your java part would be the same, you could even use <jsp:setProperty name="connect" property="*" /> this would directly set all properties with matching name